# Drop privilege to tables only, Not to database

Tags: mysql, permissions, users

I created a user with drop privilege to a database.

How can I create a user who has the privilege to drop tables of a specified database, but not database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do `GRANT DROP ON TABLE thedatabase.* TO user1`.
The [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html) is a great place to look for this kinds of things.

Comment: There I need to specify table name. right? Suppose if there are 100 tables in a database, I need to give this 100 times. Is there any quicker method?

Comment: And also what if user created a table himself. I need to give this grant to that table also

Comment: You don't need to define that per table, I corrected the omission of the database name, but `thedatabase.*` stands for "all tables in database named `thedatabase`"